# My game lags when the sound plays when my hero node makes contact with coins in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

There is a bit of a hitch in my game when the sound plays when my hero node collects coins. Why does this happen? Here is my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate,    
GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {    

var popSound =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath:      
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pop", ofType: "wav")!)

var popAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

popAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: popSound, error: nil)

 }


   if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && 
   secondBody.categoryBitMask == CoinCategory {
        coinAudioPlayer.play()
        coinAudioPlayer.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(1.0)
        coinAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
     }
```